# row with max value per group - SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Given a table with `columns(name, lat, lon, population, type)` where there are many rows for each **name**, I'd like to select the rows grouped by **name** where **population** is the highest. The following works if I restrict myself to just name and population

```
SELECT name, Max(population) 
FROM table WHERE name IN ('a', 'b', 'c') 
GROUP BY name;
```

But I want the other columns — `lat, lon, type` — as well in the result. How can I achieve this using SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join against that result to get the complete table records

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM your_table t1
JOIN 
(
    SELECT name, Max(population) as max_population
    FROM your_table 
    WHERE name IN ('a', 'b', 'c') 
    GROUP BY name
) t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
    and t1.population = t2.max_population
```

Answer (score 12):

SQLite allows you [to just list the other columns you want](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg); they are guaranteed to come from the row with the maximum value:

```
SELECT name, lat, lon, Max(population), type
FROM table
WHERE name IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
GROUP BY name;
```

The docs read:

> Special processing occurs when the aggregate function is either min() or max(). Example:
>
> ```
> SELECT a, b, max(c) FROM tab1 GROUP BY a;
> ```
>
> When the min() or max() aggregate functions are used in an aggregate query, all bare columns in the result set take values from the input row which also contains the minimum or maximum.

Answer (score 0):

**`RANK` or `ROW_NUMBER` window functions**

Although `max` is guaranteed to work on SQLite as mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/48328243/895245 the following method appears to be more portable and versatile:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY "name"
        ORDER BY "population" DESC
      ) AS "rnk",
      *
    FROM "table"
    WHERE "name" IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
  ) sub
WHERE
  "sub"."rnk" = 1
ORDER BY
  "sub"."name" ASC,
  "sub"."population" DESC
```

That exact same code works on both:

- SQLite 3.34.0
- PostgreSQL 14.3

Furthermore, we can easily modify that query to cover the following use cases:

- if you replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `RANK()`, it returns all ties for the `max` if more than one row reaches the max
- if you replace `"sub"."rnk" = 1` with `"sub"."rnk" <= n` you can get the top n per group rather than just the top 1